# UbuntuOne: sync to server without storing on disk first

Tags: ubuntu-one

Duplicity (Déjà Dup) seems to be able to do backups on Ubuntu One without storing the backup files locally. 
I would like to know, how would one achieve to upload a file to Ubuntu One from a shell script without storing it on the hard disk fist?
In other words: The shell script should create a folder on Ubuntu One, and copy a file directly to that directory on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicity uses the REST API to talk to the Ubuntu One server directly. You must do the same in any program where you wish to store the content directly on the server.

However, if the Ubuntu One client is configured to automatically subscribe to any folders on the server, then the data will be automatically synchronized back down to the local machine. Ubuntu One file sync is a synchronization service, not a remote file store.